# Tags Moksha and Mukti are synonymous. Aren't they?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I found that [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2200/81) question has used tags [moksha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moksha) and [mukti](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mukti). I think that both Moksha and Mukti are synonymous. So, I suggest that we either delete one of the tags or make one the synonym of the other.

Comment: They are same in a sense like, Moksha means freeing in association with god, and mukti means only free

Comment: @Mr.Alien Sorry, I don't get you.

Comment: Say for example, when we are talking about god, and say, free our souls we are referring moksha and when we say mukti it just means free, so moksha is always associated with god, where as mukti is a general term which means free.. I will wait for a day, so still you think we should merge them? And you are correct, they are synonyms in a way, but if a user is talking about mukti, he cannot use the word moksha, but if he is talking about moksha he can use mukti..

Comment: @Mr.Alien I think that we may decide after hearing the opinions of other users as well.

Comment: Yes, I'll wait, but I agree with you that they are synonyms..

Answer (score 1):

IMO, I don't think these tags are synonyms to each other. As per my understanding:

- **Moksha**: The person will be out from the cycle of Life and death and will reside in the abode of God with eternal peace.
- **Mukti**: Being freed from one life form. For example, there are many Devtas who were cursed to become a monster and being freed (*mukti*) if someone (*mostly Incarnation of gods*) kills them i.e the monster.

Comment: But in South India, I have heard people using these two terms interchangeably.

Comment: @Dharmaputhiran I am from South India. AFAIK, they are not interchangeable.